# Azure Devops - Bulk Assoiate Automated Test Case to Story

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests

In order to associate an automated test case to a story for requirements traceability you have to 
1. Go to the pipeline that contains the results of the automated test case
2. Click the link UI button and enter the associated story
This has to be done one by one and if you want requirements traceability for more than one pipeline, you have to do it for each pipeline.

Is there a bulk way to associate automated test cases to the associated stories in specific pipelines? Otherwise it is a painful process to associate each test case to a story using an Agile process.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , I am afraid there is currently no out-of-the-box feature to achieve it . By exporting work items to [excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process) for batch modification, we can modify almost every field except Links.

In our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a similar [suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/467635/add-link-remove-and-link-add-to-work-item-bulk-edi.html) exist in it.However, due to inactivity, the ticket has been closed, you can submit a new suggestion ticket according to your situation.

At present, we can batch link multiple work items to a work item.

[image]

As a workaround , you can try to link two work items with [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-link) , with this method, you only need to modify the id to link.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.1
```